# What does "restricted" mean in Data Usage

Tags: mobile-data

When I go to Settings - Data Usage, next to some of the apps it says "restricted." The only thing I can restrict is background data, which I've done for all the apps. But only some of them say restricted. What does this mean?

Comment: @beeshyams Sure that's a dupe? OP asks for restricting mobile data for apps – while your link points to declaring some WiFi hotspots to be counted as "mobile connection". // **Kathleen:** A screenshot might help for clarification :)

Comment: @izzy that's why added the comment after marking it dupe, since there is ambiguity . You did right by asking for screen shot

Comment: Hopefully there will be one soon, @beeshyams – but the answer by UglyBlueCat sounds convincing to me :)

Comment: Retracted close vote

Answer (score 1):

It is referring to the restriction of background data.

This list only shows apps that have used, or attempted to use, mobile data in the current cycle period, which is shown underneath 'Set mobile data limit' and should be set to match your billing period.

Comment: Thanks for the response @UglyBlueCat. From what you and my husband said, my interpretation is that an app that says "restricted" tried to access background data, but was blocked by my having turned it off. The other apps (where I also turned off background data) may have accessed foreground data. I wish Android allowed you to restrict foreground data also.